# Start Android Activity from notification and pass extra to it

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to start an Activity from a Notification that I am creating in a FirebaseMessagingService. My problem is that I cannot pass custom action and extra to my ResultActivity in that case if ResultActivity is not in the stack and it is firstly created. In this case the ResultActivity get the intent with the `android.intent.action.MAIN` without the extra. Can somebody help what could be the problem, and how I can pass the notificationId extra to my Activity?

```
private fun sendNotification(remoteNotification: RemoteMessage.Notification, data: Map<String, String>) {
    val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
    createNotificationChannel(notificationManager)

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_text_info)
        .setContentTitle(this.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString())
        .setContentText(remoteNotification.body)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(
            getNotificationContentItem(
                data.getOrDefault(NOTIFICATION_DATA_KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_DATA_KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID)
            )
        )
        .build()

    notificationManager.notify(getRandomNotificationId(), notification)
}

private fun createNotificationChannel(notificationManager: NotificationManagerCompat) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        channel.description = CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

private fun getNotificationContentItem(notificationId: String): PendingIntent? {
    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
    notificationIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    notificationIntent.action = ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_DETAILS
    notificationIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId)

    var flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        flags = flags or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    }

    val builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
    val pendingIntent = builder.run {
        addNextIntentWithParentStack(notificationIntent)
        getPendingIntent(0, flags)
    }
    return pendingIntent
}
```

Comment: Can you also show how you are retrieving the extra in your activity?

Comment: Just calling `intent.getStringExtra(NotificationService.EXTRA_NAME_NOTIFICATION_ID)` in the onCreate function of the Activity

Comment: I tried your code on a real device and for it works fine.